# Is it possible to sagetex without Sage installation?

Tags: installing, sagetex

Is it possible to use sagetex without Sage installation if I have an account in the Sagemath Cloud?

Comment: You asked this question in your comment yesterday [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225324/how-to-run-lualatex-or-sagetex) and I replied (yesterday) you could and gave more instructions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can as described in paragraph 5 of doc.

Comment: Can you expand a bit?

Comment: doc: ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/sagetexpackage

Comment: A link to the docs https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/sagetex.pdf